# Changing color of paragraphs in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am writing a response to reviewers in R markdown and would like my responses to be blue while the reviewer text stays black. It will be a back and forth, so black paragraph followed by blue paragraph about 50 times. I am knitting into a PDF. I started out successfully with this code in the YAML:

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{color}
```

and then `\textcolor{blue}{response bla bla.}` in line for the responses.

It worked for a while, but now I get an error message:

```
! Paragraph ended before \@textcolor was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.321
```

I've been spending time with LaTex trying to figure this out, but I barely know where to start.

Comment: instead of marking individual sections you could save the .tex output of your original and your new files then run latexdiff via the command line. It will produce exactly what you are trying to do manually.

Comment: "It worked for a while...": then you should try to isolate the part where it doesn't and show us that code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is likely that rmarkdown is messing up latex but we cannot know how without code.

Comment: @scoa I agree it would be helpful to all of us if I could isolate the problem, but I'm not sure where it is. I'm afraid that `\textcolor` is only meant for a few words, but not a whole paragraph. I can only find it in the context of very short examples.

Comment: To isolate the problem: use `output: pdf_document: keep_tex: true`, compile, open yourfile.tex, go to line 321, find the corresponding code in your rmarkdown file, remove everything else, and see if the problem persists ; if it does, post that paragraph

Comment: Extremely helpful. I was looking at 321 in my rmd file, but there was a '%' that jumped out at me in the .tex file.